# Retrieve slf4j config file from outside war file

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, war

Where can i store SLF4J configuration file so that all production and test environment may have access to it? I want to store the config file outside of the web app at an arbitrary location and retrieve that location upon startup. I also want to allow for changing location of the config file so no classpath. Im thinking about using getters and setters to retrieve the file path.

Any ideas??

Comment: Specifically what config file are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

slf4j is (for all practical purposes) just the API.  You need a backend which does the actual work.

If you use logback you can ship a logback.xml file with your application which just includes another file.  If I recall correctly the filename string can hold a `${variable}` which you can then define outside your application.

Answer (score 0):

See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty

> You may specify the location of the default configuration file with a system property named "logback.configurationFile". The value of this property can be a URL, a resource on the class path or a path to a file external to the application.
>
> `java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1`

Comment: the project is using datanucleus which uses log4j so cant use logback. Where can i put the log4j config file outside the application and how can i get the location of the config file without hard coding the classpath?

Comment: See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html: Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.